# skaffold unable to pull image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-deployment, skaffold

I have a Skaffold config file

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta26
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: libero
build:
  local:
    useBuildkit: true
  artifacts:
    - image: registry.a.com:5000/b/c/d
      custom:
        buildCommand: make docker
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - k8s/canary-a/deployment.yaml
```

The `make docker` build command corresponds to

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 $(DOCKER) build --secret id=ci-job-token,src=token .
```

I have no idea why, but when I run `Skaffold dev`,

```
#12 exporting layers done
#12 writing image sha256:95d59d2289205522ca22543767eef3852042959006af15d4f41d43306ec4640b done
#12 DONE 0.0s
getting image: GET https://registry.a.com:5000/v2/b/c/d/manifests/4.5.5-264-g248b268-dirty: MANIFEST_UNKNOWN: manifest unknown; map[Tag:4.5.5-264-g248b268-dirty]
```

Notice the **/v2** in the URL, where did that come from? Am I missing something here?
I think it's also worth mentioning that i've already ran `skaffold dev` with multiple different configurations (for example different tag policies), so that might have to do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

That `GET https://registry.a.com:5000/v2/...` is showing the underlying REST API for accessing an image registry.  That API is called the [OCI Distribution Spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/main/spec.md).

The `MANIFEST_UNKNOWN: manifest unknown` error is happening as your `make docker` is creating an anonymous untagged image, and is not fulfilling the [*Skaffold Custom Builder* contract](https://skaffold.dev/docs/pipeline-stages/builders/custom/) which requires the command to build the image named `$IMAGE`, which includes the destination repository and image tag to be used, and push the image if `$PUSH_IMAGE` is `true`.

Your `make docker` should do something like:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 $(DOCKER) build --tag $(IMAGE) --secret id=ci-job-token,src=token .
if [[ "$PUSH_IMAGE" == true ]]; then $(DOCKER) push $(IMAGE); fi
```

(My `make` knowledge is rusty, so you will likely need to adjust this!)